# Acidentalmente votei pra deixar uma questão aberta, existe alguma maneira de desfazer tal ação?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-intencional, filas-de-análise

Hoje na *fila de análise* (Votos para fechar) acidentalmente clique no botão <kbd>Deixar aberta</kbd>, no entanto o correto naquele momento seria fechar a questão.

Geralmente eu posso remover meus votos de fechamento, mas aparentemente não posso remover votos para deixar aberta uma pergunta.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isto?

Eu penso que talvez devesse haver uma tela de confirmação para evitar acidentes, um `window.confirm` simples por exemplo:

```
    <script>
    if (window.confirm("Quer realmente deixar esta pergunta aberta?")) {
        alert("Deixar aberta");
    } else {
        alert("Nada acontece");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Se te referires a [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87960/129) fechei, à espera de mais info na pergunta.

Comment: Sim @Sergio, no entanto isto pode ser algo que eventualmente pode acontecer novamente por acidente com outras perguntas na fila de analise, eu posso remover votos de fechamento, mas não votos "pra deixar aberto". Acho que isto ajudaria a reverter situações um pouco catastroficas, já que o legal dos sites da SE é que podemos fechar, abrir, editar :) - Claro que eu posso votar pra fechar posteriormente, mas um voto acidental como este pode influenciar outros usuários a confiarem na opinião de usuários mais experientes que votaram por acidente em "Deixar aberta".

Comment: Acabei de ler. Realmente me confundi nos assuntos. Para o caso em questão, não tem como reavaliar seu voto na fila de análise, mas você pode ir até a pergunta e votar para fechá-la manualmente. Acredito eu que pouco impacta se você fizer isso, pois o que é contabilizado de verdade são os votos para fechar, os votos para deixar aberta apenas pode fazer com que a pergunta saia da fila de análise um pouco mais cedo, mas não invalida os votos de quem optou por fechar.

Comment: @Math, entendo, meu medo é este voto influenciar outras pessoas, talvez por confiarem na opinião de usuários mais experientes, acabam por não ler o post e "deixam aberto". Fiquei com uma duvida, depois de fechar ou reabrir uma questão eu posso tentar fecha-la novamente ou tenho que esperar o próprio AP editar a questão?

Comment: Mas dificilmente os usuários veem os votos dos outros na fila de análise, ou eles precisam acessar o link direto, tipo isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/43050 ou precisariam de 10 mil de rep para poderem ver essa lista com a análise dos demais usuários: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history

Answer (score 9):

Você não pode remover uma análise.

"Deixar aberto" * não * vale como voto. Esta ação apenas informa ao sistema que a questão não precisa de atenção de quem pode votar para fechar. Você ainda pode votar para fechá-la, e da mesma forma outros usuários também podem. Sua análise errada apenas cria uma chance ligeiramente maior destas outras pessoas não verem a questão na fila de análise.

Comment: Espero não ter distorcido nenhuma idéia ao editar. Quem puder conferir a [original](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/4840/revisions) e revisar meus ajustes, é bem vindo.

Comment: Looks fine to me, @Bacco - all non-Englishy interspersed with proper keywords.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in answering. I'll just keep "open" the suggestion because I think there could be a "confirm button" to prevent accidents (I edited my topic).